# How to handle model change before click event with input[radio] and objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to implement a directive for uncheckable radio buttons.

**Context**:
My customer asked this feature so user can reuse the same form with different criterias, ie being able to deselect previously used fields.
In the case of this field, he want it to stay a radio button, not a select.

My current Plunker is available [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/mhg1mhxie2tDWQtx9meY?p=preview) (not working).

I've succeeded with a method in ng-click when the radio button's model uses simple string values. (see the 'sexe' field in the Plunker example)

But this totally fails when model uses objects.

Ive tried $viewChangeListeners but it doesnot trigger on reclicking on same radio button, ie it considers no change... Same problem with $parsers and ng-change.
It seems like ng-click triggers AFTER model changes...
Ideally i'd like to reset the model if radio button already checked, problem $modelValue and :checked already changed when checking in element.on("click")

So i'm trying with a directive in toggleRadioCheckedState.js:

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('formExample', [])
        .controller('FormController', FormController);
      
    function FormController () {
        var vm = this;
        var defaultCriteres = {
            site: null
        };
        vm.sites = [
            { id: 1, name: 'Nantes', address: 'address1' },
            { id: 2, name: 'Lille', address: 'address2' },
            { id: 3, name: 'Lyon', address: 'address3' }
        ];
  }
})();

(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('formExample')
        .directive('toggleCheckState', toggleCheckState);
    
    function toggleCheckState ($parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attributes, ngModelController) {
                var lastCheckedValue = null;
                element.on('click', function (event) {
                    var test = angular.equals(
                        ngModelController.$viewValue,
                        lastCheckedValue
                    );
                    console.log(
                      'lastCheckedValue before', lastCheckedValue,
                      '\n$viewValue', ngModelController.$viewValue,
                      '\nevent.target.value', typeof event.target.value,
                      '\ntest', test
                    );
                    if (!test) lastCheckedValue = ngModelController.$viewValue;
                    else {
                        ngModelController.$setViewValue(null);
                        event.target.checked = false;
                        lastCheckedValue = null;
                    }
                    console.log('lastCheckedValue after', lastCheckedValue, "\n================================\n");
                });
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<form  ng-app="formExample" ng-controller="FormController as ctrl">
    <label ng-repeat="site in ctrl.sites">
        <input type="radio" name="site" ng-model="ctrl.criteres.site"
               ng-value="site" toggle-check-state>
        {{site.name}}
    </label>
</form>
```

The problem is i'm first getting desired behavior on a single radio button, but as soon as i check other radio button then come back to previous radio button, the behavior fails...

I don't really understand why the internal var lastCheckedValue does not update properly...

Comment: *a directive for uncheckable radio buttons*: why don't you jut disable it?

Comment: Look at the [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) directive.

Comment: The click handler of the `ng-model` directive is fighting the click handler of the custom `toggle-check-state` directive. Use the [$viewChangeListeners API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$viewChangeListeners) of the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) instead.

Comment: Remove the "toggle-check-state" from  input tag of radio button it will work.

Comment: Thanks for answers.
I have added more precisions about what i want in original post.